# Can you provide an example of how to use "IN" queries in Node.js with Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I want to explain how to use the "IN" search in Node.js. 
I understand that the "IN" operator may not be supported in Node.js.
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#in

Someone help me.

Here is the code I tried.

```
const idList = [1, 2, 3];
const query = this.dataStoreClient.createQuery('namespace', 'kind')
  .filter('ID', 'in', idList);
```

An error message appeared here, for sure.

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: a property filter must specify an operator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this reference- https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/latest/datastore/query

But you check the link- https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-datastore-property-filter-nodejs

IN comparison operator we can use.
[image]

Below is an example of how to use "IN" queries in Node.js with Google Cloud Datastore:

```
    // Import the Google Cloud Datastore client

    const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
   // Create an instance of a Datastore client
   const datastore = new Datastore();

   // Create an array of the values you want to query
   const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

   // Create a query
   const query = datastore
      .createQuery('YourEntityName')
      .filter('id', 'IN', ids);

    // Run the query
    datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {
  const entities = results[0];

      console.log('Entities:');
  entities.forEach(entity => {
    console.log(entity);
  });
});
```